# Angular Material Data Table Export, different name for router link

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

[image]

This is the current situation, I have a button at header whenever I click at it it downloads the excel data from the table, currently I achieved that. Whenever the pop 
up appears the text: You have choosen to open "Table Data, excel format-2019..." 
t.s at header

```
  exportTable() {
    TableUtil.exportToExcel('ExampleTable', '');
  }
```

Also
created a t.s seperately

```
  static exportToExcel(tableId: string, name?: string) {
    let timeSpan = new Date().toISOString();
    let prefix = name || "Table Data, excel format";
    let fileName = `${prefix}-${timeSpan}`;
    let targetTableElm = document.getElementById(tableId);
    let wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(targetTableElm, <XLSX.Table2SheetOpts> { sheet: prefix });
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve-
Whenever I click a router link I want the pop-up data to change and adjust to the current route name
Like I click router 1 and click download button, pop-up appears you are about to open
1...
I click router link 2
You are about to open 2...

Router 1 html

```
  <table id="ExampleTable"   mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the Angular router from the component and listen to route changes. You can save the path url into a variable and use it to set prefix in `exportToExcel` method

```
constructor(router: Router){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        this.fileName = event.url;
    }
```

Comment: I achieved the solution slightly different thanks to this answer, your answer helped me a lot, I'm gonna add it as the best answer. Thanks a lot Palle, Chandra and Mosiiii(for the great editing!)


```
  constructor(  private router: Router
  ) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      this.fileName = event.url.split(",");
    });
  }
```